# How do I set Section-Header.xib constraints in UITableView programmatically using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set the width constraints programmatically using Objective-C.

The below code is working fine when I build my app using **`Xcode 7.2.`**

```
  [secHeaderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_sectionHeaderView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_sectionHeaderView)]];

    [secHeaderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_sectionHeaderView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_sectionHeaderView)]];
```

Now when I run my app using **`Xcode 9.3`**, then my secHeaderView's are missing. It's due to the constraints which are mentioned above.

If I comment out the above constraints, then I can see my secHeader View, but the width is not properly set. It shows 70% width of UIScreen.

This is how my secHeaderView looks, but the width is not properly set...

[image]

Here is my actual code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    _sectionHeaderView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BasicProdInfoSectionHeaderView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    SectionHeader *currentHeader = [self.titleStringArray objectAtIndex:section];

    [_sectionHeaderView setTitleWithText:currentHeader.titleLabel];
    _sectionHeaderView.expandableButton.tag = section;

    [_sectionHeaderView.expandableButton addTarget:self action:@selector(expandButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIView *secHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width , 50)];
    _sectionHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [secHeaderView addSubview:_sectionHeaderView];
    [secHeaderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_sectionHeaderView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_sectionHeaderView)]];
    [secHeaderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_sectionHeaderView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_sectionHeaderView)]];

    if (section != 3) {
        secHeaderView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        secHeaderView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
        [secHeaderView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        secHeaderView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
    }

    return secHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be 100% ?

Comment: Yeah, I need it 100%, it's should be able to run on iPad or on any iPhone devices. So it should be dynamically set it's width constraints.

Comment: UIView *secHeaderView = [[UIView alloc]init] //do not set frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple document for `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview?language=objc)

> This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.

So I guess that problem is because you didn't implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method in your class.

Another problem is you don't need to give `secHeaderView` a size inside `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` because

- A section's header will always have same width with `tableView` by default.
- The right way to change tableView section's height is using `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method.

Actually I created a new project and tried your code. It works as expected.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  _sectionHeaderView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BasicProdInfoSectionHeaderView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
  SectionHeader *currentHeader = [self.titleStringArray objectAtIndex:section];

  [_sectionHeaderView setTitleWithText:currentHeader.titleLabel];
  _sectionHeaderView.expandableButton.tag = section;

  [_sectionHeaderView.expandableButton addTarget:self action:@selector(expandButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  UIView *secHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_sectionHeaderView.frame];
  _sectionHeaderView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

  [secHeaderView addSubview:_sectionHeaderView];

  if (section != 3) {
    secHeaderView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    secHeaderView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
    [secHeaderView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    secHeaderView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
  }

  return secHeaderView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return 50;
}
```

Comment: It runs perfectly

Comment: Great explanation & also you provided me an official source for reference purpose. Thanks a lot man...you finally done it.

Comment: From so many day's I'm struggling..but you have solved my problem by providing a very simple & feasible solution. Thanks-a-lot. Great help provided to me.

Comment: Welcome :). Now I think you will always take a look at official document each time getting stuck. Maybe they can help you with a solution or some hints.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this two lines

```
[secHeaderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_sectionHeaderView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_sectionHeaderView)]];
    [secHeaderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_sectionHeaderView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_sectionHeaderView)]];
```

With

```
[secHeaderView
     addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_sectionHeaderView
    ]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"_sectionHeaderView
    ":_sectionHeaderView
    }]];

    [secHeaderView
     addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_sectionHeaderView
    ]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"_sectionHeaderView
    ":_sectionHeaderView
    }]];
```

Comment: Nope : UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000049b530 h=--& v=--& SectionHeaderView:0x7ff471190c00'SectionHeade...'.width == 320   (active)>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000049dfb0 H:[SectionHeaderView:0x7ff471190c00'SectionHeade...']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7ff46fc9b230 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000049b440 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7ff46fc9b230.width == 375   (active)>"
)

Comment: Please check this output. I'm getting this way. But I want to set width of header same as UIView width.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/f4hxK.png

Also check-out this, & plz let me know if I'm going wrong http://i.stack.imgur.com/2teEE.png

Because In this frame size is mentioned so I think that's why it is not working.

Comment: change "secHeaderView" to "self.view"
and "_sectionHeaderView" to your header view

Comment: @ChiragKothiya there is nothing different between them

Answer (score 1):

Use below constraints I have change below constraints

```
// center sectionHeaderView horizontally in secHeaderView
[secHeaderView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:sectionHeaderView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:secHeaderView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

// center sectionHeaderView vertically in secHeaderView
[secHeaderView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:sectionHeaderView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:secHeaderView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

// width constraint
[secHeaderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[sectionHeaderView(==0)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sectionHeaderView)]];

// height constraint
[secHeaderView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[sectionHeaderView(==0)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sectionHeaderView)]];
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. I'm getting this error's : breaking constraint

Comment: Please check this output. I'm getting this way. But I want to set width of header same as UIView width. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4hxK.png

Comment: Also check-out this, & plz let me know if I'm going wrong
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2teEE.png

Comment: Because In this frame size is mentioned so I think that's why it is not working.

Comment: Yes firstly, I have added constraints for labels, uiimages but now I have cleared all constraints but same issues is existed.

Comment: please comment this line     _sectionHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; and check it again.it work for me @AndreoKllings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172059/discussion-between-vidhi-patel-and-andreo-kllings).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this. You dont have to set the frame for the section superview. As tableview sets its autolayout automatically.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    _sectionHeaderView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BasicProdInfoSectionHeaderView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    SectionHeader *currentHeader = [self.titleStringArray objectAtIndex:section];

    [_sectionHeaderView setTitleWithText:currentHeader.titleLabel];
    _sectionHeaderView.expandableButton.tag = section;

    [_sectionHeaderView.expandableButton addTarget:self action:@selector(expandButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIView *secHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _sectionHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [secHeaderView addSubview:_sectionHeaderView];
    [_sectionHeaderView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:secHeaderView.bottomAnchor constant:0]
    [_sectionHeaderView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:secHeaderView.leadingAnchor constant:0]
    [_sectionHeaderView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:secHeaderView.trailingAnchor constant:0]


    if (section != 3) {
        secHeaderView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        secHeaderView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
        [secHeaderView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        secHeaderView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
    }
    [secHeaderView layoutIfNeeded]

    return secHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: Getting this error => Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000294870 SectionHeaderView:0x7f8c2505b000'SectionHeade...'.height == 0   (active)>

Comment: if you have height constraint set in storyboard you could either remove it or remove [ _sectionHeaderView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:secHeaderView.topAnchor constant:0]

Comment: Please check this output. I'm getting this way. But I want to set width of header same as UIView width. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/f4hxK.png

Comment: Also check-out this, & plz let me know if I'm going wrong 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/2teEE.png

Comment: Because In this frame size is mentioned so I think that's why it is not working.

Comment: Did you remove UIView *secHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width , 50)]; ?

Comment: Yes I removed that.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please make sure no constraint or edge insets set on your xib. If this does not work, I would suggest you debug using interface debugger and see how the frames are set.

Comment: @Andreo Kllings I don't know why a wrong answer can be marked. This code not only can't be complied but also giving an unexpected result.